# Laying out responsive images with text in Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: intended layout]

I'm trying to create a layout similar to the one pictured above at the top of my page. Im using bootstrap 4, and I've created the appropriate row and column arrangement

```
        <div class = "row">
          <div class = "col-sm-2"> </div>
          <div class = "col-sm-1" > Image goes here</div>
          <div class = "col-sm-1" > Image goes here </div>
          <div class = "col-sm-8"></div>
        </div>

        <div class = "row">
          <div class = "col-sm-2"> </div>
          <div class = "col-sm-1"> <!-- -->  </div>
          <div class = "col-sm-5">
            <div class="row">Title Text goes here </div>
            <div class="row"> More text goes here </div>
          </div>
          <div class = "col-sm-4"></div>
        </div> `
```

my biggest issue comes with defining the size of the images. I would like for them to maintain a certain aspect ratio, and decrease in size (while maintaining the ratio) for smaller displays. I tried fixing the size of the columns and setting the image dimensions to fill the columns, but that doesn't work. also trying to modify the size of the images themselves make them stick out of the grid.
Also is there anyway where i can control the size at which a column wraps?

Comment: Please remove the extra spaces after the class attributes.

Comment: use img-fluid  class just in where you write container

Comment: @nikhilsugandh i tried that, and now it responds correctly, but now it starts at a small size. How do i set an initial max height and width? (i tried using max width and height:auto, but it doesnt have an effect)

Comment: it will start form thats size only in grids but working responsive??

Comment: @nikhilsugandh I can't specify the starting size. it starts very small, and it only gets smaller.

Comment: give it a max-height and max width that will do

Answer (score 0):

heres the code for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid  img-responsive"">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2" > </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
        <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
        <img src="2.jpg" class="img-responsive"  > </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2"> </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1"> <img src="3.jpg " class="img-responsive" ></div>
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5">text goes here </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>

            <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

you just put some images and see
check out the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/tyu867tk/

Comment: @nikhiil sugandh no, the images are still locked at a certain size (changing the width and height doesnt seem to affect them). Note that I also tried adding the "img-fluid" class to them.